# Array inside an map function seems to receive data, outside the map it was empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, express, prisma

I'm making a simple GET and POST with NodeJS and Express just for learning a little about PrismaJS with MySQL database. I want to pass the value of the array **grouped** to the creating function, when I use console.log(grouped) inside the map function I have the values I want, outside it keeps empty [], also when I'm passing him to connect field.

```
async function createUser(name, email, groups) {

  const grouped = [];

  groups.map(async (item) => {
    const exist = await prisma.group.findUnique({where: {id: item }})
    if(exist) {
      grouped.push({id: item})
      console.log(grouped) //here is ok
      
    } else {
      console.log(`Group ${item} does not exist`)
    }
  })
  
  console.log(grouped) //here he is []

  const creating = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      groups: {
        connect: grouped //here he is [], should be like [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
      }
    }
  })

}
```

Comment: if my answer fixed your problem - please approve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is with the `async (item) => { ...` I mean the function of the `map` function ... you should wait for all the map inner function to finish so just change your code to the following:

```
async function createUser(name, email, groups) {

  const grouped = [];

  await Promise.all(groups.map(async (item) => {
    const exist = await prisma.group.findUnique({where: {id: item }})
    if(exist) {
      grouped.push({id: item})
      console.log(grouped) //here is ok
      
    } else {
      console.log(`Group ${item} does not exist`)
    }
  })
)

  
  console.log(grouped) //here he is []

  const creating = await prisma.user.create({
    data: {
      name: name,
      email: email,
      groups: {
        connect: grouped //here he is [], should be like [{id: 1}, {id: 2}]
      }
    }
  })

}
```

notice the `Promise.all()` iv'e added before the map, this extra line will wait for *all* the inner functions of the map.

Comment: Thanks, it really works. I'm still learning how to write code with JavaScript also, so there's a bunch of ground to cover regarding basic concepts.